# PHP Form - How to Hide Content Form Options That Arent Filled In

Tags: php, forms

I am currently making a simple PHP contact form for a company I work for. It includes some checkboxes, and some text areas, this is the php code.

```
   <?php

function getPost($name){
return ( isset($_POST[$name])? $_POST[$name] : '');
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$landline = $_POST['landline'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$pclandline = getPost('pclandline');
$pcmobile = getPost('pcmobile');
$pcemail = getPost('pcemail');
$zptf = getPost('zptf');
$zpf = getPost('zpf');
$zpsf = getPost('zpsf');
$opz = getPost('opz');
$opfg = getPost('opfg');
$opfs = getPost('opfs');
$tpz = getPost('tpz');
$tpf= getPost('tpf');
$zpfoct= getPost('zpfoct');
$opzoct= getPost('opzoct');
$zptfquan = $_POST['zptfquan'];
$zpfquan = $_POST['zpfquan'];
$zpsfquan = $_POST['zpsfquan'];
$opzquan = $_POST['opzquan'];
$opfgquan = $_POST['opfgquan'];
$opfsquan = $_POST['opfsquan'];
$tpzquan = $_POST['tpzquan'];
$tpfquan = $_POST['tpfquan'];
$zpfoctquan = $_POST['zpfoctquan'];
$opzoctquan = $_POST['opzoctquan'];
$promo = $_POST['promo'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Email : $email \n Confirm Email : $email2 \n Landline: $landline \n Mobile: $mobile \n PC Landline: $pclandline \n PC Mobile: $pcmobile \n PC Email: $pcemail \n \n 0.25l: $zptf \n 0.25l Quantity: $zptfquan \n 0.5l: $zpf \n 0.5l Quantity: $zpfquan \n 0.75l: $zpsf \n 0.75l Quantity: $zpsfquan \n 1.0l: $opz \n 1.0l Quantity: $opzquan \n 1.5lg: $opfg \n 1.5lg Quantity: $opfgquan \n 1.5ls: $opfs \n 1.5ls Quantity: $opfsquan \n 2.0l: $tpz \n 2.0l Quantity: $tpzquan \n 2.5l: $tpf \n 2.5l Quantity: $tpfquan \n 0.5l Octime: $zpfoct \n 0.5l Octime Quantity: $zpfoctquan \n 1.0l Octime: $opzoct \n 1.0l Octime Quantity: $opzoctquan \n Promotional Code: $promo \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "replaced email";
$subject = "Glass Sweet Jars Quote";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank you! We will contact you as soon as possible with your quote" . " -" . "<a href='index.html'>Return Home</a>";
?>
```

My question is, when I receive the email it lists EVERYTHING on the form, whether the user has checked or written in it, which makes it quite time consuming picking out the relevant data, is there any way to hide any areas not filled in by the user in that particular email?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't add it to $formcontent if the variable is not set...

Answer (score 0):

Use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if the variable is set and filled.. If true add into form variable, otherwise ignore..

```
$formcontent = "";
$formcontent .= !empty($email)? "Email : {$email}<br />" : "";
$formcontent .= !empty($confirmemail)? "Confirm Email : {$confirmemail}<br />" : "";
```